# Is it possible to catch errors between chained promises?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I am wondering if this works?

```
S3.getObject()
  .promise()
  .then()
  .catch() // catch error from the first then() statement
  .then()
  .catch() // catch error from the second then() statement
```

or do I need to place all 'catches' in the end? Can I have multiple catch then? Will they be fired in the order of the 'then' statements throwing errors?

Comment: Yes, your current code should work just fine, if you want to have separate `catch`es for each `.then`, though note that if the `.then`s are expecting values from the previous promise, the `catch`es will have to return something usable by the next `.then`

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: If the function in your catch throws or returns a rejected promise the .then after the catch will not be executed but code will go to the following catch. If the catch doesn't throw or return a `Promise.reject(value)` the next then will be executed with the return value.

Comment: Guys why not post it as an answer, then I can accept it :) Don't want the score? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of your actual goals.

As a matter of fact, `.then()` method takes two parameters:

- *onFullfilled*: Callback to be invoked when the promise is fulfilled.
- *onRejected*: Callback to be invoked when the promise is rejected.

In fact, `.catch(fn)` is just a shorthand for `.then(null, fn)`.

Both `.then()` and `.catch()` each return a new promise which **resolves** to its return value. In other words:

- A resolved promise of that value if it isn't a promise.
- The actual return value if it is already a promise (that will be fulfilled or rejected).
- A rejected promise if the return value is a rejected promise (as previous point says) or any error is thrown.

The main reason behind the use of `.then(onFullfill).catch(onReject)` pattern instead of `.then(onFullfill, onReject)` is that, in the former (which is equivalent to `.then(onFullfill).then(null, onReject)`), we are chaining the `onReject` callback to the promise returned by first `.then()` instead of directly to the original promise.

The consequence of this is that if en error is thrown inside the `onFullfill` callback (or it returns a promise which happen to resolve to a rejected state), it will be catched by the chained `.catch()` too.

So, answering to your question, when you do something like:

```
P.then(...)
 .then(...)
 .then(...)
 .catch(...)
;
```

You are chaining promises "supposing" all will go fine "and only check at the end". That is: Whenever any step fails, all subsequent `.then()`s are bypassed up to the next (in this case the last) `.catch()`.

On the other hand, if you insert more `.catch()`s in between, you would be able to intercept rejected promises earlier and, if appropriate, solve whatever were going on and turn it into a resolved state again in order to resume the chain.